# Symfony2 applying entity validation constraint to the equivalent form type

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, entity

Is there a way to use the same validation.yml  so the constraints applied to entites are applied to the formtype as well

for instance, if title field in entity is 50chars max length, title field in formttype should have the same constraint well ( at least in my case )

so we can avoid specifying max length in the add-method of the formtype like so ,

```
$builder->add("title", "text", array('max_length' => 50));
```

In summary

how to use entity validation constraint in formtype so same constraints ( required, max length,  etc) are auto applied ?

I was wondering how to get the validator service and convert it to array in the formtype class... is it the good approach ?

but this approach make me read enity validator for each entity in each form.....

Answer (score 1):

You can set validation on your entity and this validate whenever this entity will called:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

and on your annotation comments add:

```
@Assert\Length(max="255",maxMessage = "Title cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters length")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,Yes i know that, but it is entity validation level, i would like to have the same constraint on a formtype which use this kind of entity.

Comment: If you bind your form to the data class it will do that already though.